# FFmpeg video transcoding outputs rectangle-looking bad quality pixels

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to convert a video with FFmpeg using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.AVI -vf yadif output.mp4
```

the original video looks like this:
[input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HdVk.jpg)

the output is like this, it gets worse gradually in the video:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1QrT.jpg)

full command line output:

```
ffmpeg version 4.2.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.1.1 (GCC) 20190807
  configuration: --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.1 : mono
Input #0, avi, from 'D:/samples/GSchneller.AVI':
  Duration: 00:00:48.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4549 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main) (H264 / 0x34363248), yuv420p(top first), 720x576 [SAR 1:1 DAR 5:4], 4426 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_u8 ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 8000 Hz, mono, u8, 64 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (pcm_u8 (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[aac @ 0000021440118640] Too many bits 8832.000000 > 6144 per frame requested, clamping to max
[libx264 @ 0000021440115c80] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0000021440115c80] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0000021440115c80] profile High, level 3.0, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0000021440115c80] 264 - core 158 r2984 3759fcb - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2019 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'D:/samples/output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 720x576 [SAR 1:1 DAR 5:4], q=-1--1, 25 fps, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 8000 Hz, mono, fltp, 48 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 aac
frame= 1161 fps=231 q=-1.0 Lsize=   20382kB time=00:00:48.00 bitrate=3478.6kbits/s speed=9.56x
video:20131kB audio:230kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.101893%
[libx264 @ 0000021440115c80] frame I:5     Avg QP:24.11  size: 68270
[libx264 @ 0000021440115c80] frame P:324   Avg QP:26.47  size: 31484
[libx264 @ 0000021440115c80] frame B:832   Avg QP:29.51  size: 12106
[libx264 @ 0000021440115c80] consecutive B-frames:  2.4%  4.0%  6.5% 87.2%
[libx264 @ 0000021440115c80] mb I  I16..4: 16.4% 29.9% 53.7%
[libx264 @ 0000021440115c80] mb P  I16..4:  7.8% 13.2% 11.2%  P16..4: 36.3% 17.7%  9.7%  0.0%  0.0%    skip: 4.2%
[libx264 @ 0000021440115c80] mb B  I16..4:  2.2%  3.4%  1.3%  B16..8: 44.0% 14.5%  4.9%  direct: 8.3%  skip:21.3%  L0:49.2% L1:41.8% BI: 9.0%
[libx264 @ 0000021440115c80] 8x8 transform intra:43.6% inter:46.3%
[libx264 @ 0000021440115c80] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 75.5% 63.1% 16.4% inter: 36.0% 41.3% 7.4%
[libx264 @ 0000021440115c80] i16 v,h,dc,p: 27% 38% 16% 20%
[libx264 @ 0000021440115c80] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 16% 23% 30%  7%  4%  3%  6%  5%  7%
[libx264 @ 0000021440115c80] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 27% 34% 12%  4%  4%  3%  6%  3%  6%
[libx264 @ 0000021440115c80] i8c dc,h,v,p: 49% 26% 21%  4%
[libx264 @ 0000021440115c80] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.6% UV:0.6%
[libx264 @ 0000021440115c80] ref P L0: 54.2% 17.0% 19.2%  9.5%  0.1%
[libx264 @ 0000021440115c80] ref B L0: 84.7% 12.4%  2.8%
[libx264 @ 0000021440115c80] ref B L1: 94.6%  5.4%
[libx264 @ 0000021440115c80] kb/s:3551.05
[aac @ 0000021440118640] Qavg: 58278.074
```

I drew the black rectangles to hide the plates.

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hm. That seems like a bug with the encoder. Or do did you get the same weird artifacts when using `-c:v mpeg4`?

Comment: yea I got the same result when using `-c:v mpeg4`.

Comment: Does the problem occur with another input video, or does it just affect this particular one?

Comment: it occurs with several videos from this one customer. the original video codec is MPEG4 AVC (part 10), I've tried to reproduce it with other videos witht the same codec but from other sources but to no avail.

what drives me crazy is that VLC converts the videos with no problem and they use FFmpeg for this stuff (I think).

Comment: ok so I will update this question when I'm good enough to read  the VLC source code to find out how this works.

Comment: Then it seems like a decoder problem or simply a broken input video. Although there are no errors logged… You could file a bug report on https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ if you can supply a sample video. VLC *does* use the same underlying libraries but in a different version.

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues:

1) first is that ffmpeg will automatically set a bitrate or quality parameter if not specified. For `mpeg4`, that bitrate will be `200 kbps`. OK for VCD caps in 1995, not for today's standards. Set a high enough bitrate e.g. `-b:v 1500k`, or a quality factor `-q:v 3`.

2) second, the source video is interlaced (jagged lines), as can be seen in the still image of the original. To deinterlace, use a deinterlacing filter such as `yadif`.

So, full command would be

```
ffmpeg -i input.AVI -vf yadif -vcodec mpeg4 -q:v 3 output.mp4
```

Comment: thanks. 
the deinterlacing worked, but the problem with the video quality is still there.

Comment: Reduce `q:v` to 1 or switch to `libx264` encoder, dropping the `q:v`

Comment: unfortunately this still didn't help. VLC can convert it though no problem. 
my co-worker thought it might have something to do with the keyframe setting, I used -g 1 but that also didn't work.

Comment: the original video codec is mpeg4, I dropped the -vcodec libx264 and the problem still persists, so we know that it's not an issue with codec.

Comment: Please update your question with the command you're using currently, and show the full, uncut command line output.

Comment: See OP's update, apparently a decoder bug or problem with the particular encoded sequences.

Comment: Not exactly a decoder bug. I've seen this before. AVIs can't correctly store H264/5 streams so if the decoder gets packets in the wrong order, it may produce this result. To the OP, extract the stream and work on that: `ffmpeg -i input.avi -c copy raw.264`

Comment: that didn't help unfortunately, but I think I found a temporary solution: using the api, I set a time_base of 1/90000 to the AVFormatContext->streams[videoStream]->time_base right after I opened the file and the video seems to be correctly converted. if I don't set the timebase, it will be automatically set to 1/12800. I don't know how to replicate that in command line though.

Comment: You can add a filter `-vf settb=1/90000`